# Change input autocomplete value

Tags: javascript, input, autocomplete

I have another question: Is there any way to change input autocomplete value dynamically with javascript?

Example:

```
<input id="myInput" 
       placeholder="Write something here..." 
       onchange="changeAutocompleteValue(event)">

<script>
    function changeAutocompleteValue(event)
    {
        var list = ["first", "second", "third"];
        event.list = list;
    }
</script>
```

Google example:
[image: Google searching]

Am I able to do it with plain JS? Any suggestion will be great :).

Comment: not worth an answer, but i have this plain JS library that you or anyone coming to this page in the future may be interested in: https://github.com/danqing/autocomplete :)

Comment: @Danqing Great idea! Anyway, I was too stupid then :D Honestly, I would make a library to solve this problem just in one hour or less :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found

[javascript : Auto complete javascript text field](http://www.vonloesch.de/node/18)

if use existing library then

[typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

[typeahead.js / example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

```js
function loadXMLDoc(_target, _type,_func) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               
             
              data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
             
              _func(data);

           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400')
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(_type, _target, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function ontxtChange(){
 var dcc = document.getElementById('autocc');
  var dc = document.getElementById('autoc');
  dcc.innerHTML = ' ';
 var i = 0;
var target = "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos"


// 

if(dc.value.length > 0){
  
  
loadXMLDoc(target,'GET',function(data){
    data.forEach(function(x){
      
      if(i < 10){
        
        if(x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(dc.value.trim()) != -1){
              dcc.innerHTML += '<p class="accItem">' + x.name.toLowerCase() + '</p>';
         i++;  
        }
      
      }
     
    });
});
  
  }
}
```

```css
.accItem{
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
  width:200px;
}

#autocc{
 width:200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id="autoc" onkeypress="ontxtChange()" > example : "am"
<div id="autocc">
  
</div>
</body>
```

suggestion--

- condition in call ajax (slow with big data)
- condition in send/receive data with ajax

hope help you this way...

Comment: I don't know, @wit_peter, because your first example doesn't work for me (I have mozilla). I can programme [divs and spans](http://prntscr.com/65uy7l), like typehead, it's not really hard for me, but I want to know the way, how to change this autocomplete value :/

Comment: you really want to help me, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will need to write much more code. Your best option to use existing library that handles this for you:

Documentation: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Demo: http://devbridge.github.io/jQuery-Autocomplete/

Comment: Sorry, but I need JUST plain JS, not jQuery...I know it's really easy to do it with jQuery, but I can't do it with jQuery...

Comment: I am actually working on the version without jQuery dependency. Will be releasing it soon. Let me know if interested.

Comment: I've "solved" this question with divs, because I don't want to waste time, also, I've found that google uses divs, too...but, I think on the world is lots of people with this problem and they solve them with `divs` and `spans`. When you want to make version without JQuery, you can also look on input autocomplete list styling, if it's possible :) Cheers  :)